# pymongo and python: issue with find document using date filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

I am trying to retrive document from mongodb using pymongo and python from these mongodb collection.

```
{
  "fees": "0.00",
  "trigger": "immediate",
  "price": "18.30000000",
  "recordTimestamp": "2023-01-10T12:03:27.197000Z"
},
{
  "fees": "4.00",
  "trigger": "immediate",
  "price": "12.30000000",
  "recordTimestamp": "2023-02-10T12:03:27.197000Z"
},
{
  "fees": "1.00",
  "trigger": "immediate",
  "price": "10.30000000",
  "recordTimestamp": "2023-03-10T12:03:27.197000Z"
}
```

If I use mongoDB compass and do this filter

```
{recordTimestamp: {$gte: '2023-01-24',$lte: '2023-03-01'}}
```

I get below expected result.

```
{
  "fees": "4.00",
  "trigger": "immediate",
  "price": "12.30000000",
  "recordTimestamp": "2023-02-10T12:03:27.197000Z"
}
```

however when I use same filter in pymongo I get nothing.

```
stdateval = datetime(2023,1,24)
endateval = datetime(2023,3,1)
dtFilter = { "recordTimestamp" : {"$gte": stdateval,"$lt": endateval}}

collection = DBModule.database[collectionName]
jsnObj_list = collection.find(dtFilter)
```

What am I doing wrong?

btw I tried this alternative and it also gets the expected result. but not with pymongo find option.

```
stdateval = datetime(2023, 1, 24)
endateval = datetime(2023, 3, 1)

jsnObj_list = collection.find({})

filtered_list = []
for item in jsnObj_list:
    recordTimestamp = datetime.strptime(item['recordTimestamp'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    if stdateval <= recordTimestamp < endateval:
        filtered_list.append(item)
```

Comment: It looks like you've stored the date as a string type in the database, but you're querying with a date type in pymongo. Likely better to correct the data

Comment: data is dumped from a json file and there is lot of date feilds and other values. This is just an extract of the data. I am trying to figureout how to filter them by dates so that I can pick only latest and then convert them into appropriate formats.

Comment: Your comment seems to be orthogonal to mine, the problem, and the solution. The docs you shared show the information in `recordTimestamp` is stored as a string type. Filters in queries do not implicitly convert between types, so using a date won't match anything (since, again, the data is stored as strings). So update your documents to use dates, change your query to use strings, or use a query that does the conversation dynamically. The first approach is really the only scalable one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing solution I found.

resolved using filter

```
{
  "$or" : [
   { 'recordTimestamp': {$gte: '2023-01-24'} },
   { 'recordTimestamp': {$lte: '2023-03-01'} }
   ]  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should store your dates as a BSON date types. If you are stuck with strings then you can do:

```
stdateval = '2023-01-24'
endateval = '2023-03-01'
dtFilter = { "recordTimestamp" : {"$gte": stdateval,"$lt": endateval}}
```